# Change Source Commit

Tags: git

I have the following structure:

```
A-B-C-D (branch-C)
  \    \
   \    H (branch-A)
    \
     \-E-F-G  (branch-B)
```

I would LIKE this:

```
A-B-C-D  (branch-A and branch-C)
  \    
   \    
    \
     \-E-F-G-H  (branch-B)
```

How do I do this?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of labeling a couple of branches for you; this will help answers be better.

Comment: Added branch C to make it even better :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have branch-B checked out:

```
git cherry-pick branch-A
git push . branch-C:branch-A -f
```

You now have the option to delete either branch-A or branch-C - or just keep both.

Comment: This isn't very useful without branch names - there's a good chance that the OP will end up moving a branch he doesn't want to. Perhaps give names to the branches that start out at G and H?

Comment: This will move branch A, and you'll "lose" B-C-D. They'll still be there, but there won't be a branch pointing to them.

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout branch-B
git cherry-pick branch-A  # you could also specify H directly
```

Now you have H atop G.

```
git checkout branch-A
git reset --hard HEAD^    # you could also specify D directly
                          # HEAD is the current commit; HEAD^ is the previous one
```

Now you've removed H from the branch which contained A-B-C-D.

Note that this only has meaning if there's some branch ref pointing to H and G at the start, since a commit object in git incorporates it ancestors; "moving" a commit doesn't mean anything insofar as it changes your branches.

Comment: To the OP: replace G and H with the branches that have started out at those commits. (This is what Borealid is getting at with the last paragraph, but I think it's a little clearer this way.)